# Reading lines from a text file into a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a text file on my desktop, `lines.txt`:

```
lines stuff stuff
lines lines
boats boats lines
```

And all I'm trying to do is read it into a variable, but every time I print it, I get an empty list. Here's my code:

```html
inF = 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/text.txt'
    def repeatWords(inF):
            import string
            infile = open(inF, 'r')
            text = infile.readlines()
            infile.close()
            print(text)
repeatWords(inF)
```

When I `print(text)`, all I get is an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that's the file you're opening (i.e. the version on the desktop, rather than somewhere else)?

Comment: Post your full code. I don't see any print call here. May be it is outside of the function and you've defined text = [] there.

Comment: Where do you call `print(text)`?  Immediately after the call to `readlines()`?  (Your function doesn't return anything; are you missing `return text`?)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, a line before I have inF set to the file path, C:\users\me\desktop\file.txt

Comment: Please **edit the question** to include a correctly-formatted [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Edited. I'll try return, but is that any different than setting a variable to the file?

Comment: so how you call the function ? please add all of your code !!!!!!

Comment: Whoops, added. First day here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with your code. I have no idea where you call `print(text)`, but it needs to be *after* it is assigned to. Here's a corrected version:

```
def repeat_words(in_f, out_f):
    with open(in_f, 'r') as infile:
        text = infile.readlines()
        print(text)
```

Comment: I got it to work with this, thanks. I'm not sure why it wasn't working for me...

Is opening the file the way you did it better than infile = open(inF, 'r') ?

Comment: @royalflush5 Yes, a context manager is always preferred whenever possible. The corner case I can think of where it can't be used, is when you need to use a stream as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think you called `text` out side the function . Note that **Variables inside the functions have a local scope** so you need to call `text` inside the function !

Answer (score 0):

```
file_object = open("myfile", 'r')
for line in file_object:
    print(line)
file_object.close()
```